# How to optimize the login option in android?

Tags: android

HI,

I want to create Login option in my application , so that once a person gets login that device creates token which is saved over server. From next time whenever he/she operates the application, directly goes to next label by checking that token keyvalue pair over server.IT requires login page only when that keyvalue pair is deleted from the server.

Can anyone help me from this.I will be very grateful to you.
Looking for reply.

Regards,
Praween

Comment: Hi Praween. This question is difficult because it is very broad, and a little hard to follow. Certainly it sounds like what you suggest is possible on Android, but you will need a good knowledge of secure RPCs to complete this project.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the token on the device in either a SQLite db or in a preference ([Android - How Do I Set A Preference In Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552070/android-how-do-i-set-a-preference-in-code)).  When your main login page is created, try to retrieve that token and if it exists, continue onto the next page passing the retrieved token.