# Android how to get specific preference?

Tags: android, xml, android-preferences, preference

I have the following code in my application in res/xml/preferences.xml:

---

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<PreferenceCategory android:title="Wi-Fi settings">


   <EditTextPreference
            android:key="pref_voice_threshold_top"
            android:title="@string/title_pref_voicetopthreshold"
            android:dialogTitle="@string/dialog_title_pref_voicetopthreshold" 
            android:defaultValue="20"
            android:inputType="number"/>

</PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

---

And I was wondering is it possible for me to then use this preference in code so I can update it via downloading an xml file?

So I currently display the above preference in a PreferenceActivity, which works fine, however I want to be able to update the setting by downloading a new setting every week from the internet.

So my question is how do I open this preference in code and set its value to the new downloaded value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As McStretch said, you have to get the preference with

```
sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("com.yourname.yourapp_preference", 0);
Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

editor.putString("your_optionname", "newValue");
// Save
editor.commit();
```

The com.yourname.yourapp_preference is the name of the xml file. It's typically located at /data/data/com.yourname.yourapp/shared_prefs/com.yourname.yourapp_preference.xml

Just check out that directory in to see how your file is named, but basically it should by default be packagename_perference.xml

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this post in order to grab a Preference `Editor` object:  [How do I set a preference in code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552070/android-how-do-i-set-a-preference-in-code)

Before you get the `Editor`:

Parse the XML to get your desired preference values, and then use the `Editor` to retrieve the correct preference and subsequently set it.

Comment: Thanks but what do I use as the String in getSharedPreferences? I have tried getSharedPreferences("pref_voice_threshold_top", 0) and getSharedPreferences("Wi-Fi settings", 0) but both return null.

Comment: Since you're using a PreferenceActivity, you could use this method: public Preference findPreference(CharSequence key) found in PreferenceActivity.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear on that part, I need to be able to set the Preference from outside the PreferenceActivity, so in this case I am not using a PreferenceActivity where I want to set the Preference