# Android: reading Preferences in code

Tags: android, preferences

Is there a way to perform an action related to a Preference in a PreferenceActivity? I've been using this:

```
CheckBoxPreference thing = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("thing");
thing.setChecked(true);
```

The first line runs okay but the second line results in a NullPointerException. These lines are inside the onCreate() method in my code. Ideally I want to use an onClicked() signal so that I can run certain methods when preferences are changed. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: are there meant to be two different thing objects? or are you really trying to say thing is based on itself?

Comment: Please provide a full context if you want useful answer.

Comment: Apologies, it should have been "thing" in the second part - this refers to an object defined in XML. The code is correct, I just typed it in wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using an onSharedPreferenceChangedListener which you can set on a PreferenceScreen

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceScreen.html

Answer (score 0):

**thing is NULL** -- > maybe then prefference with 'thing' refference doesn't exist

I recomend you to read [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552070/android-how-do-i-set-a-preference-in-code)

Answer (score 0):

`public Preference findPreference (CharSequence key)`, so what is the thing argument ⇒ try `findPreference("thing")`

**Update:** [That blog entry](http://www.kaloer.com/android-preferences) may be of use to you.